# Force checkout new items

Tags: event-receivers, check-out

I would like to force check out documents to the owner of the document when it is added.  I am currently doing this when a new item is added via a workflow.  I'd like to achieve this via an event handler/receiver.  Does anyone have the code to share with me?

Comment: If you require documents to be checked out for editing in the library settings, they will automatically be checked out to the person who uploads them. No code needed that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to do the following:

1. In the library settings click "Versioning settings"
2. Set "Requite Check Out" to true
3. Done

[image: require checkout]

**Update:**

I've just realized that you need to check out the document when you are adding it, not editing...

Then [this might work for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkout.aspx):

```
SPListItem.File.CheckOut
```